# Android Generate QR Scan image

Tags: android

I wish to generate a QR image so people can scan to visit my Android market.

However, I need to specify a search param like:   market://search?q=MyStringHere

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I tend to use the ZXing Web Generator for creating QR code images.

http://zxing.appspot.com/generator/

Just use "URL" for the contents and use the market://search?q=String you want to reference.

Answer (score 1):

Check out App Referrer, a free app that will generate these codes for you, and can email you an image to post on your site.

Answer (score 1):

Google is your friend: http://code.google.com/apis/chart/ -> Chart Wizard -> Show Full Gallery -> choose the QR chart, put your URL in and voila, copy the QR image.